# changing columns to column header pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this-

```
 A  B  C
 a  2  4
 b  4  6
 c  4  8
```

I want to create a new  empty dataframe with columns like this-

```
a b c class
```

where the rows of first column of first dataframe become the columns in new dataframe and another column['class'].
I did a simple df.pivot[columns='A'] but the results were wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first take all Col A data as list

```
>>> col = df.A.tolist()
>>> col.append('Class')
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, Class]
Index: []
```